# Android NDK warning on compiling jni directory in r9d

Tags: compilation, android-ndk

Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/e/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/jni/Android.mk:mu‌​pdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries [armeabi-v7a] Compile : mupdf <= mupdf.c /bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/Users/MEHDI/Downloads/Compressed/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86/android‌​-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-an‌​droideabi-gcc: No such file or directory make: *** [/cygdrive/e/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/ob‌​js/mupdf/mupdf.o] Error 127

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use GCC 4.4.3 which is no longer distributed with the NDK. Did you set NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION in your environment? If so, please undefine it and re-run the command.

Apart from that, the warning is perfectly normal. You should use LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS if you want to export dependent system libraries for your static library. LOCAL_LDLIBS is only used when building a shared library or executable.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ndk-build` on Windows does not need cygwin, and some of its components cannot work with cygwin. Run `ndk-build.cmd` from Windows CMD shell, and avoid hardcoding `cygdrive` anywhere.
2. The warning you get is legitimate. You probably have `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)` in your `Android.mk`: this module does not use linker, therefore it does not need `LOCAL_LDLIBS` neither `LOCAL_LDFLAGS`. I would not worry about this warning, if this is the only problem in your build.

If you need more help with your project, please post the `Android.mk` file (or fragments of it), and also the `Application.mk` if you have one.